# Batch rename URLs in XML file

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++, rename

I have a list with URLs and IPs for Office365 in XML format. Now I'd like to either write a script or use a text editor's search and replace function (regex) to automatically change some of these URLs.

Example:

These URLs

```
  <address>scus-odc.officeapps.live.com</address>
  <address>scus-roaming.officeapps.live.com</address>
  <address>sea-odc.officeapps.live.com</address>
```

Should be changed to

```
  <address>*.officeapps.live.com</address>
  <address>*.officeapps.live.com</address>
  <address>*.officeapps.live.com</address>
```

I would appreciate any input on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1)Search for .*.(?=[^.]*.[^.]*$) and replace with an empty string.This does a good job but unfortunately it removes the preceeding  as well...

2)As pointed out by Tim, the list consists of FQDNs with different domains.The list is available from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=533185 (This list includes all FQDNs - The IPs will get deleted)

3) Solved with the help of Sergio's input. The solution was to
search for `(>)[^.\n\s]+` and substitute with `\1\*`
I will have to write another script to delete the multiple domains but that was not part of the question so I consider this issue closed. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Please include your own efforts and solution attempts in your questions.

Comment: Please show your actual data.  Some of your addresses could have one or more subdomains, making it difficult to write a single pattern to cover everything.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  Your list of domains is _massive_, and no one should have to read through that file to help you.  It is up to _you_ to give us a minimal problem, the solution to which you can go and use for your actual problem.

Comment: @Tim Thank you, I was able to solve the problem with this command provided by Sergio: Search for (>)[^.\n\s]+ and substitute with \1\* .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex:

[`(>)[^.\n\s]+`](https://regex101.com/r/kG0uE1/8)

and substitute with `\1\*`

Comment: That seems to work extremely well. But it leaves the list with multiple entries of the same domain... I will look into this!